# Solidity - Updating timestamp value in a deployed contract

Tags: timestamp, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have an auction contract that's supposed to run for say 20 minutes.

To facilitate this, I have an `auctionEndTime` variable which I initialize in the `constructor` as follows:

```
  auctionEndTime = block.timestamp + 20 minutes;
```

But what if I wanted to update the `auctionEndTime` by adding some additional minutes to it?

I wrote a function that lets me pass in the value of the additional minutes I'd wanna add to my `auctionEndTime` variable, as follows:

```
function changeAuctionEndTime(uint extraTimeAmount) public {
    require(msg.sender == contractOwner, "ONLY THE CONTRACT's OWNER CAN CALL THIS FUNCTION!");  
    auctionEndTime += newEndTime minutes;  
}
```

But this immediately gives me the following error:

```
Expected ';' but got 'minutes'
```

And it's giving me a squiggly red line under the word `minutes`.
So it's clearly not liking something right there.  (And note that this error appears immediately - as-in, it's not like I compile and get this error, it's that I can't even compile and run the code as is.)

So what's going on? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your variable is `extraTimeAmount` and not `newEndTime`.
2. Suffixes like `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `days` and `weeks` after **literal** numbers can be used to specify units of time. (From official docs).
3. So you need to do `extraTimeAmount * 1 minutes` instead of `extraTimeAmount minutes`.

Here is your piece of code that will work as per above points -

```
function changeAuctionEndTime(uint extraTimeAmount) public {
    require(msg.sender == contractOwner, "ONLY THE CONTRACT's OWNER CAN CALL THIS FUNCTION!");  
    auctionEndTime += extraTimeAmount * 1 minutes;  
}
```

Comment: NICE - and so simple. (And yes, I was copy-pasting my code and also editing it on the fly so I messed up my variable names - sorry for the inconsistency, and glad you caught it!)